# MacBook Pro Boots to a circle with a line through it

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

My MBP boots-up to only a circle with a line through it.  I have no idea what this means.  It will not let me go into *single-user mode* or *recovery mode*.  I'm assuming everything is gone.  I don't have the disks that came with it.  I don't know OS X, can someone help me and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean it displays what is the called the "Prohibitory symbol", as described on this Apple Support page? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204156

Comment: @gentlemanhog just pointed out your answer.  good work!

Comment: @fbara - it might be the answer on a newer Mac, but on an 09 the simplest fix is 'take it to an Apple Store' - it doesn't have Internet Recovery & the OP said he'd already tried Recovery.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was referring to the OP's question about what that icon meant and not how to fix it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the official designation of the Prohibitory Symbol was not the OP's prime motive for asking the question ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin I was just trying to clarify what the OP saw.